# C# Combo DataBinding to Empty Guid shows 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have windows form with a Combo filled with 3 options where their values are Guid's and that has a DataBinding to a selected object.

```
EmployerMemberDefault item = EmployerMemberDefault();
item.GroupUid = Guid.Empty;

cbGroupEmployer.DataBindings.Clear();
cbGroupEmployer.DataBindings.Add("Value", item, "GroupUid");
```

When I create a new object the property that is databinded to the combo is set to Guid.Empty. If I compile and run, when I create that new object I see "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" in the combo. Is there any way I can see empty text in the combo instead of the Guid.Empty value?

Thanks.

Comment: [`Guid.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty.aspx) is a guid whose value is all zeros. When you `ToString()` this (which is what happens when it shows in the combo), you get what you have. You need to deal with this value specifically if you want it to display as an empty string.

Comment: A ComboBox doesn't have a "Value" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the source property from `Guid` to `Guid?`/`Nullable<Guid>`  I haven't done this with Guid, but it works with `int`/`DateTime` and other types that do not allow null.

Answer (score 1):

"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" is what Guid.ToString returns.  To show something different you'd have to translate that value in some way--i.e. bind to something else that stores the guid and translates it.

Comment: Indeed, +1 for the simplicity. OP could have a custom class `MyGuid` that overrides `ToString` to test if it's equals to `Guid.Empty` and then return `String.Empty` or something like it. A little overkill, though.